# ng-click not working in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

so I have this Angular application I'm working on.
I have a controller called **visualization** and a directive called **force-layout**.

In the HTML template of the directive I'm creating three buttons and I attach to them three corresponding functions that I define in the directive code:

```
    <div class="panel smallest controls">
        <span ng-click="centerNetwork()"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span ng-click="zoomIn()"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span ng-click="zoomOut()"><i class="fa fa-search-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>

    <force-layout ng-if=" config.viewMode == 'individual-force' || config.viewMode == 'individual-concentric' "></force-layout>
```

The function are defined in the directive like this:

```
    scope.centerNetwork = function() {
      console.log("Recenter");
      var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(d) { return (d.id == sourceId)})[0];
      svg.transition().duration(750).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width/2-sourceNode.x, height/2-sourceNode.y));
    }
    var zoomfactor = 1;
    scope.zoomIn = function() {
      console.log("Zoom In")
      svg.transition().duration(500).call(zoom.scaleBy, zoomfactor + .5);
    }
    scope.zoomOut = function() {
      console.log("Zoom Out")
      svg.transition().duration(500).call(zoom.scaleBy, zoomfactor - .25);
    }
```

It does not trigger any error.
It was working before, not it is not and I cannot understand what is causing the problem, any help?

---

UPDATE: full directive code.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name redesign2017App.directive:forceLayout
 * @description
 * # forceLayout
 */
angular.module('redesign2017App')
  .directive('forceLayout', function() {
    return {
      template: '<svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('drawing network the first time');
        // console.log(scope.data);
        var svg = d3.select(element[0]).select('svg'),
          width = +svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
          height = +svg.node().getBoundingClientRect().height,
          nodes,
          links,
          degreeSize,
          sourceId,
          confidenceMin = scope.config.confidenceMin,
          confidenceMax = scope.config.confidenceMax,
          dateMin = scope.config.dateMin,
          dateMax = scope.config.dateMax,
          complexity = scope.config.networkComplexity;

        var durationTransition = 500;


        // A function to handle click toggling based on neighboring nodes.
        function toggleClick(d, newLinks, selectedElement) {

          // Some code for handling selections cutted out from here

        }

        svg.append('rect')
          .attr('width', '100%')
          .attr('height', '100%')
          .attr('fill', 'transparent')
          .on('click', function() {
            // Clear selections on nodes and labels
            d3.selectAll('.node, g.label').classed('selected', false);

            // Restore nodes and links to normal opacity. (see toggleClick() below)
            d3.selectAll('.link')
              .classed('faded', false)

            d3.selectAll('.node')
              .classed('faded', false)

            // Must select g.labels since it selects elements in other part of the interface
            d3.selectAll('g.label')
              .classed('hidden', function(d) {
                return (d.distance < 2) ? false : true;
              });

            // reset group bar
            d3.selectAll('.group').classed('active', false);
            d3.selectAll('.group').classed('unactive', false);

            // update selction and trigger event for other directives
            scope.currentSelection = {};
            scope.$apply(); // no need to trigger events, just apply
          });


        // HERE ARE THE FUNCTIONS I ASKED ABOUT

        // Zooming function translates the size of the svg container.
        function zoomed() {
          container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + ", " + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");
        }
        var zoom = d3.zoom();
        // Call zoom for svg container.
        svg.call(zoom.on('zoom', zoomed)); //.on("dblclick.zoom", null);
        //Functions for zoom and recenter buttons
        scope.centerNetwork = function() {
          console.log("Recenter");
          var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(d) {
            return (d.id == sourceId) })[0];
          svg.transition().duration(750).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width / 2 - sourceNode.x, height / 2 - sourceNode.y));
          // svg.transition().duration(750).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
        }
        var zoomfactor = 1;
        scope.zoomIn = function() {
          console.log("Zoom In")
          svg.transition().duration(500).call(zoom.scaleBy, zoomfactor + .5);
        }
        scope.zoomOut = function() {
          console.log("Zoom Out")
          svg.transition().duration(500).call(zoom.scaleBy, zoomfactor - .25);
        }

        // TILL HERE

        var container = svg.append('g');

        // Toggle for ego networks on click (below).
        var toggle = 0;

        var link = container.append("g")
          .attr("class", "links")
          .selectAll(".link");

        var node = container.append("g")
          .attr("class", "nodes")
          .selectAll(".node");

        var label = container.append("g")
          .attr("class", "labels")
          .selectAll(".label");


        var loading = svg.append("text")
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr('x', width / 2)
          .attr('y', height / 2)
          .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
          .attr("font-size", 10)
          .text("Simulating. One moment please…");

        var t0 = performance.now();

        var json = scope.data;

        // graph = json.data.attributes;
        nodes = json.included;
        links = [];
        json.data.attributes.connections.forEach(function(c) { links.push(c.attributes) });
        sourceId = json.data.attributes.primary_people;

        // d3.select('.legend .size.min').text('j')

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
          // .velocityDecay(.5)
          .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(function(d) {
            return d.id;
          }))
          .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-75)) //.distanceMax([500]))
          .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
          .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
            if (d.id == sourceId) {
              return 26;
            } else {
              return 13;
            }
          }))
          // .force("x", d3.forceX())
          // .force("y", d3.forceY())
          .stop();

        for (var i = 0, n = Math.ceil(Math.log(simulation.alphaMin()) / Math.log(1 - simulation.alphaDecay())); i < n; ++i) {
          simulation.tick();
        }

        loading.remove();

        var t1 = performance.now();

        console.log("Graph took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds to load.")

        function positionCircle(nodelist, r) {
          var angle = 360 / nodelist.length;
          nodelist.forEach(function(n, i) {
            n.fx = (Math.cos(angle * (i + 1)) * r) + (width / 2);
            n.fy = (Math.sin(angle * (i + 1)) * r) + (height / 2);
          });
        }

        function update(confidenceMin, confidenceMax, dateMin, dateMax, complexity, layout) {
          // some code for visualizing a force layout cutted out from here
        }

        // Trigger update automatically when the directive code is executed entirely (e.g. at loading)
        update(confidenceMin, confidenceMax, dateMin, dateMax, complexity, 'individual-force');

        // update triggered from the controller
        scope.$on('Update the force layout', function(event, args) {
          console.log('ON: Update the force layout')
          confidenceMin = scope.config.confidenceMin;
          confidenceMax = scope.config.confidenceMax;
          dateMin = scope.config.dateMin;
          dateMax = scope.config.dateMax;
          complexity = scope.config.networkComplexity;
          update(confidenceMin, confidenceMax, dateMin, dateMax, complexity, args.layout);
        });

      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Please add your full directive code.

Comment: “working before, now it is not”. So, file compare with previous versions. Do you use version control? (if not, why not?) Do you make backups? (if not, why not?) Which IDE do you use? (if none, why not?) Both Eclipse and Netbeans keep a local history every time you save the code. Just right click & select “Compare with … local history” and compare the current version with the previous, then the one before that, etc, until you find what you broke

Comment: Wow, your directive is more a controller than a directive. Your template shows a `svg` and not the three buttons you told us.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! We use Version Controls, but we are not understanding what is causing the problems. We are noob on Angular and so directives and controllers might not follow best practices, sorry for that :)

The three buttons are in the upper code I pasted and it is extracted from the controller template HTML file.

Comment: Well, yea. Your code looks like you guys are juniors. Well in that case, please read the basics of using directives and refactor your codes: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found the problem.

The directive was invoked by the `<force-layout>` tag, which presented the `ng-if='some-condition'` directive.

For some reason, while the controller code is evaluated, that condition doesn't prove to be true, and the directive as a whole, meaning its HTML and its JS, is simply skipped: the `ng-click` is then obviously not able to attach the click event to a function that does not exists yet.

Replacing `ng-if` with `ng-show` solved the issue: apparently in this case the code is executed immediately and the directive exists hidden, with all its declared properties.